# Angular unit test, how to test a subject as observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable, behaviorsubject

I am trying to test a subject as observable, but it is not working as expected 
For simplistic I have removed extra logic inside getService2Test subscribe

Below is my function in service class

```
getTest():Observable<string>{
   let subject = new Subject<string>();
   service2.getService2Test().subscribe(result=>{
        subject.next(result.success);   // result.success = "testing"
        subject.complete();
   });
   
   return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Below is my test case

```
it('Testing getTest()',()=>{
   spyOn(service2,'getService2Test').and.returnValue(of("success"));
   service.getTest().subscribe((result)=>{
        expect(result).toEqual("testing");        // never gets invoked in testing
        console.log("Output result: "+result);    // not able to see any message
   });
});
```

The code inside subscribe never executed.
I am also getting a warn message of  '... has no expectations.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test case doesn't wait for your subscribe and is instantly finished. To fix this implement the resolve callback like this:

```
it('Testing getTest()', done => {
   spyOn(service2,'getService2Test').and.returnValue(of("success"));
   service.getTest().subscribe((result)=>{
        // verify results
        done();
   });
});
```

[Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)

Comment: Now I am getting 'Async function did not complete within 5000ms'

Comment: That error occurs because of the order of calls. When calling getTest() the getService2Test() is immediately fired which causes the returned subject to be completed. I think the easiest way to solve this is changing `of("success")` to `of("success").pipe(delay(0))` which forces it to run in the next cycle. Other solution would be to use schedulers or create a subject (instead of the `of`) and call `next` after subscribing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Felix, I have tested and below code works

```
it('Testing getTest()', done => {
   spyOn(service2,'getService2Test').and.returnValue(of("success").pipe(delay(0)));
   service.getTest().subscribe((result)=>{
        console.log(result);   // Prints my results
        done();
   });
});
```

Comment: what is service2? could you elaborate  a better example?